# dynamics crm 2016 - Web API query- dynamic values

Tags: javascript, rest, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to form a query to retrieve related record properties in the new Dynamics CRM (2016) Web API. But I am unable to pass the GUID value dynamically unlike in CRM 2011-2015.

```
function getRelatedEntityStartAndEndDates(){

    var parentOpportunity = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("rb_opportunityid").getValue()[0].id;

    var clientUrl =  Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();

    var query = clientUrl +"/api/data/v8.0/opportunities(5e0f714-a0c6-e511-812b-061cb19131a3)?$select=rb_enddate,rb_startdate"; 

    alert(query);

}
```

Since the new query doesn't have quotes around GUID, I'm unable to pass on the **parentOpportunity** dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to strip off the curly braces, like this:

```
var query = clientUrl +"/api/data/v8.0/opportunities(" + parentOpportunity.slice(1, -1) +  ")?$select=rb_enddate,rb_startdate";
```

As an aside, the [CRM Rest builder](https://crmrestbuilder.codeplex.com/) is a great tool to help you construct REST queries.

Comment: does crmrestbuilder need to be installed into 2016 crm or can i run it frmo VS? i'm havnig trouble

Comment: It's a solution that you would install into the org. If you want something you can run outside of CRM, check out FetchXml Builder and Linqpad...both will generate OData queries for you.  If your org is online, you'll have a much easier time getting the FetchXml Builder working.  There are probably other tools out there by now too, if anyone knows of others, please share.